# English translation of Krittivasi Ramayana

Tags: ramayana, translation-request

Per Wikipedia:

> **Krittivasi Ramayan** or Krittibasi Ramayan or Sri Ram Panchali, composed by 15th century Bengali poet **Krittibas Ojha**, is a translation of the Ramayana into Bengali.
>
> Written in the traditional Ramayan Panchali form of Middle Bengali literature, the Krittivasi Ramayana is not just a rewording of the original Indian epic, but a vivid depiction of the society and culture of Bengal in the Middle Ages.

Is an English (or at least a Hindi) translation of the same available for free or for purchase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a 2-volume English translation of Kṛttivāsa Rāmāyaṇa for sale on Eastern Book Linkers' [website](http://www.eblindology.com/book_detail.php?bookid=103).

> Kṛttivāsa Rāmāyaṇa
>
> Composed by the sage Kṛttivāsa, the sacred son of the soil.
>
> Author:   Dr. Shanti Lal Nagar
>
> ISBN: 81-86133-64-7
>
> Edition:  1998
>
> Language: English

Front & Back Cover:

[image: front] [image: back]